# adjust the source of an image

Tags: jquery, image

I have a div. I want to add an image to a div using jquery.

What i am doing

```
$('#b').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="numbers/"+rand+".png" />');
```

but it is not working. I want the `src` attribute to be as `numbers/rand.png` where `rand` is a variable. How can i make it work ?

I have tried this in a different way too

Here is what i have tried

```
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');

        // give it an id
        img1.attr("id");
        alert(img1.show());
        // source, link
        img1.attr('src','"numbers/"+rand+".png"');

        $("#b").appendTo(img1);
```

This also not worked. Where am i doing wrong ? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#b').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="numbers/' + rand + '.png" />');
```

You were using the wrong type of quotes around `"+rand+"`.

Comment: Try ` img1.attr('src', 'numbers/'+rand+'.png');`